# Using C# to fire a JavaScript event that requires JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json

My webpage is displayed in my Web Browser Control. I pass JSON To call a JavaScript event within it.

```
Object jArray = {"triggerEvent('do-this','{""name"":""" + Name + """}')"};
webBrsr.Document.InvokeScript("eval", jArray)
```

The problem is when `Name` contains an apostrophe, making it invalid. I'm looking for a different way to call JavaScript events in C# using Web Browser control.

The apostrophe is not conflicting with the JSON specifically but with the `triggerEvent`.

Comment: Pass encoded `Name` and decode it in `triggerEvent` function

Comment: I would suggest you to prepare a C# model class and serialize it to JSON string using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(event)`

Comment: The apostrophe as JSON is not the problem. The problem is that it invalidates the tiggerEvent. 

Is it possible to serialize the entire triggerEvent?